# Typescript function signature incorrect when method is from an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Has anyone ran into this issue when you get a method from an object, the function signature is not correct?

```
interface Fruits {
  shape: string
  size: number
}

interface Vegetable {
  color: string
  weight: number
}

const Foo = {
  fruit: (param: Fruit) => param,
  veggie: (param: Vegetable) => param
}

const bar = (key: keyof typeof Foo) => {
  return Foo[key]
}

const baz = bar('veggie')
//  inspect baz and it will give you a union type

const quz = baz({color: 'red', weight: 10})
//  the param type refers back to fruit
```

Comment: Wait, is `Foo` supposed to be an object or a type?

Comment: @Vilx - it's an object, but I figured out the issue, I'm supposed to use `extends`

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot, the solution is

```
const bar = <T extends keyof typeof Foo>(key: T) => {
  return Foo[key]
}
```

and typescript will get the type correctly